# dojo dijit.form.DateTextBox constraints not working, datetextbox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

Hi I'm new to javascript and dojo.  I'm trying to use two dijit DateTextBoxes with the drop-down calendars to establish a date range for a query on a database.  I want to restrict the dates available, once the begin or end date has been selected, so that its impossible to pick an end date that is chronologically before the begin date, and vice versa.  I'm trying to apply the example called 'changing constraints on the fly' (about half way down the page) from the dojo reference here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html  However, the constraints aren't working in my code.  The only thing I'm really doing differently is using the`tundra` theme.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
  </script>
</head>

<body class="tundra">
  <div>
    <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
    <input id="fromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" required="true" onChange="dijit.byId('toDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];" />
    <label for="toDate">To:</label>
    <input id="toDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" required="true" onChange="dijit.byId('fromDate').constraints.max = arguments[0];" />

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that each DateTextBox is operating within its own execution context, so they don't 'see' each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael!  I tried your suggestion, but without any luck.  And I don't understand why the constraint isn't being set, even when I hard-code a date like you suggested.  Also, my guess is that 'arguments[0]' is the first value in the arguments property of each DateTextBox object, which is updated if the user selects a date; which then would be a valid js date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new, HTML5-conform attribute `data-dojo-type` introduced in Dojo 1.6, the way how widget attributes are parsed has changed as well (to validate in HTML5 too). Widget-specific attributes are now in an HTML attribute called `data-dojo-props`, in a JSON-style syntax.

To make your example work again, either put the `onChange` (and `required`) in `data-dojo-props` (note that you have to wrap a function around it):

```js
 dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>


<body class="tundra">
  <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
  <input id="fromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="onChange: function() {dijit.byId('toDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];}, required: true" />
  <label for="toDate">To:</label>
  <input id="toDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="onChange: function() {dijit.byId('fromDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];}, required: true" />
```

Or you use the old `dojoType` instead of `data-dojo-type`, then the `onChange` attribute would be parsed. Note that it would not be HTML5-conform, but in my opinion more elegant.

Comment: If you use the first solution, you can also add a parameter to the function: function(date) {...} and then use date instead of arguments[0]. Would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I someday do some like:

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");

some_function(minDate) {
  dijit.byId('toDate').constraints.min = minDate;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<body class="tundra">
  <input id="fromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="onChange: some_function(this.value);">
```

I hope that it help you.

Comment: yes, but I was looking for a way to create a valid date range with two dateTextBoxes

Answer (score 0):

Searching for an effective date range and restrictions, where only can have a range in the past, adding the **constraints** max with echoing the date in this format `Y-m-d`, I manage to edit it like this, hopes this help.

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<body class="tundra">
  <form>
    <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
    <input id="fromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="onChange: function() {dijit.byId('toDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];}, required: true, constraints:{max:'<?PHP echo date(" Y-m-d "); ?>'} "
    />
    <label for="toDate">To:</label>
    <input id="toDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="onChange: function() {dijit.byId('fromDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];}, required: true, constraints:{max:'<?PHP echo date(" Y-m-d "); ?>'} " />
    <button onclick="dijit.byId('fromDate').reset(); dijit.byId('toDate').reset();" type="reset">reset</button>
    <button type="">Generate</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: you're calling php functions.  It looks like it will work, but I only want to use javascript/dojo

Answer (score 0):

I never had any luck with the attributes in the template like that.

I ended up just handling it on the function I run when either change:

I have one with an attach point of "startDatePicker" and another with "endDatePicker". Here I'm setting the endDatePicker to add constraints based on the new startDate someone selected so it's dynamic:

```
this.endDatePicker.constraints.min = new Date(startDate);
this.endDatePicker.constraints.max = new Date();
```