# Disable future dates in Dojo Date Picker?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, dojo

I want to disable future dates in dojo date Picker .

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"/>
```

Comment: someone answered this same question for me here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8743757/906048

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dijit.byId('textBoxID').constraints.max = new Date();
```

I'm no dojo expert, but I think that should do it. Subtract 1 day from the new date if you want to disallow today as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mycal" data-dojo-type="dijit.Calendar" value="2009-08-07" data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate:dojo.date.locale.isWeekend"></div>
```

```
 dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // loads the optimized dijit layer
 dojo.require("dijit.Calendar");

dojo.ready(function () {
    new dijit.Calendar({
        value: new Date(),
        isDisabledDate: function (d) {
            var d = new Date(d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            return dojo.date.difference(today, d) < 0;
        }
    }, "mycal");
});
```